# How to build dev version of python datatable on macos (getting pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable)

Tags: python, h2o, py-datatable

Following the directions on the `datatable` page  https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

[image]

So I ran this:

```
$pip3 install git+https://github.com/h2oai/datatable
```

The result is :

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/h2oai/datatable
  Cloning https://github.com/h2oai/datatable to /private/var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-hv991zd2
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/h2oai/datatable /private/var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-hv991zd2
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 178, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 362, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 169, in prep_for_dist
    self.install_backend_dependencies(finder=finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 123, in install_backend_dependencies
    reqs = req.pep517_backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 71, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    'config_settings': config_settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 162, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable
```

This is not actionable for me: I'm not certain what to fix/ how to proceed. Hints?

Note: in the meantime I have installed version 0.10.1 as follows:

```
sudo pip3 install 'datatable==0.10.1'
```

This has important `by` (expression based `groupby`) and `sortvalues()` that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this error occurs because you're trying to build `datatable` using an old version of `pip`. In order to build `datatable` from source, `pip` version 20.0 or higher is required.

Unfortunately, [there is no way](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4145) for a project to specify that it needs a specific minimum version of pip. And I presume if such setting would eventually be added, only the newest versions of pip would know about it anyways, defeating the purpose.

Comment: I confirmed having `19.3.1` on the machine I had tried to build with